# Why would I prefer an enum to a struct with constant values

Tags: c#, struct, enums

A struct with constants:

```
public struct UserType
{
  public const int Admin=1;
  public const int Browser=2;
  public const int Operator=3;
}
```

And now let's use an enum for the same purpose:

```
public enum UserType
{
  Admin=1,
  Browser,
  Operator
}
```

Both are allocated on the stack. In both cases I will say UserType.Admin. And with the  struct way I will not have to cast to int to get the underlying value.I know that with the enum version it's guaranteed that one and only one of the three values will be used, whereas with the struct version any integer can be used, which means any value between Int32.MinValue and Int32.MaxValue. Is there any other benefit of preferring enums besides this one?

Comment: "I know that with the enum version it's guaranteed that one and only one of the three values will be used ..." As Jon Skeet points out in his answer, this is not really true.

Comment: With enum, you can assign any value outside of Enum was declared,

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> Is there any other benefit of preferring enums besides this one?

Clarity.

Suppose you have a field or a method parameter which will always have one of those three values. If you make it the enum type, then:

- You can't accidentally assign it some arbitrary integer value. (You can *deliberately* cast any `int` value to the enum type, but you'd have to do so explicitly.)
- It's clear what kind of information that value is meant to represent

These are *incredibly* important benefits in writing code which is easy to maintain in the future. The more you can make your code naturally *describe* what you're trying to achieve, the better.

Comment: You just can't call him "dear John" (or maybe u can). Whatever i really mean, its better you knew this:
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts

Comment: What do you mean by cast an int value to the enum type? If I were trying to do something like have the option for a user to change the number represented by an enum, would that be better suited for a struct or a class?

Comment: @Adjit: In terms of casting, I mean exactly what I say, e.g. `(SomeEnum) intValue`. For the rest of your comment, we'd need more context - that sounds like an odd requirement. Maybe just a `Dictionary<EnumType, int>`

Comment: Well for my context, I am reading information off of spreadsheets, and I want to use the column names with a corresponding index. If the spreadsheet layout were to change for some reason, I'd want the user to be able to change those values instead of me having to update the program

Comment: @Adjit: That doesn't sound very related to this question, to be honest. I suggest you think about it yourself, and ask a new question if necessary.

Answer (score 9):

Enums can be looked up from Strings or Numbers without Reflection, e.g.

```
// VERY important when using ORMs, as databases usually use an int
UserType ut = (UserType)2; 

// Useful when parsing config files like appSettings.
UserType utf = (UserType)Enum.Parse(typeof(UserType),"Admin");
```

There's a lot more going on in the framework to make common operations with Enums quicker. Another thing is the [FlagsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.FlagsAttribute.aspx) for Bitfields, which is not easily possible with const ints.

Check the members of the [Enum class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.aspx) for more helper functions, e.g. GetNames and GetValues.

Comment: Well you certainly *can* combine const ints easily in a bitwise fashion, e.g. with the `|` operator. It just doesn't give you the string representation as pleasantly. (Personally I think there's a lot wrong with the way enums work in .NET. They could give us far more benefits than they do, but that's another matter :)

Comment: @Jon Indeed, instead of being better C enums, borrowing more from Java enums would have given some benefit. But yeah, having magic integers as first class citizens is the one and only thing enums in C# do.